# How to pass a fixed width to a column in a Vuetify HTML table?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I'm using a [Vuetify table](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tables/) and based on a configuration I want to set fixed column widths. I thought it would be fine to assign the width from the configuration to the `width` CSS attribute.

The first example ( [Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlkEFuwjAQRa8SeU1iWsomShFVVz0DZpHgqeLWdix7CEWIu9c2gYSgVkjsPN8z8+b/1YG8GZO1WyA5KRCUkSXCgukkKdoUy0qeCl9iDSXvilDayzt+Jg73El4Z2QmOdZ7MplPzw8jivZHJU0Gx/r993nc/X3X74kwKen9DgVXD938exBcf3k5E91cPPgJlYOeKcllc0D4Er/fxkAkRyjQWU1Wa7Ms12ud3CCOs+3CM5ElUguYDDjUjNaJxOaUbrv0YBylam2lAqo2iS99G7VajUJDyRi1n2Sx7oVw4HMoZOJVWttk5sH4JI5MBBsXn/g5U1xkJ8xOhk1JZVi4gblZTz2vBphY0Bwv2XkejsaGr0deNs0A/Mn30eUuhv90o6o2LMa/ORz5kOS4Lm9YBeJyQeKcnxwGy/gW4cgLR) ) should display a table with a total width of 350px. When having a look at the playground you will see that the table takes the whole screen width instead.

```
<template>
  <v-table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 300px">Col 1</th>
        <th style="width: 50px">Col 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-table>
</template>
```

The second example ( [Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlkEFuwjAQRa8SeU1iWtouohRRddUzYBYJnipubceyh1CEuHttE0gIaoXEzvM9M2/+X+7JmzFZuwGSkwJBGVkizJlOkqJNsazksfAl1lDyrgilPb/jZ+JwJ+GVka3gWOfJy3Q6NT+MzN8bmTwUFOv/+2eD9seLdl+cWEHvryiwavjuz5P4/MMbiuz+7sFHoAwMXVDOiwvax+D1PiAyIUKZxmKqSpN9uUb7BPdhhHUfjpE8iUrQfMShZqRGNC6ndM21H+MgRWszDUi1UXTh26jdaBQKUt6oxSybZU+UC4dDOQOn0so2WwfWL2FkMsCg+NzdgOo6I+H5SOikVJaVC4ir1dTzWrCpBc3Bgr3V0Whs6Gr0deUs0A9MH3zeUuhvN4p67WLMy9ORd1mOy8KmVQAeJiTe6clxgKx+AQZNAzI=) ) should display a table with a total width of 6300px. The first column should be too big for the screen so there should be a horizontal scrollbar. Instead the table shrinks the first column down to a smaller width so the whole table fits the screen width.

```
<template>
  <v-table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 6000px">Col 1</th>
        <th style="width: 300px">Col 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-table>
</template>
```

How can I disable this behaviour? The table should have exact columns widths ( based on the configuration values ). I tried

- `<v-table style="min-width: none; max-width: none">` no changes
- `<v-table style="overflow: auto">` no changes
- `<v-table style="width: max-content">` works if table is smaller than screen size, prevents scrollbar
- `<v-table style="width: min-content">` is too small
- `<v-table style="width: auto">` no changes

but unfortunately that didn't fix it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: _"When having a look at the playground you will see that the table takes the whole screen width instead."_ - and _inspecting_ the result using your browser dev tools, you can easily spot that the table has `width: 100%` applied to it, coming from a rule with selector `.v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table`

Comment: I updated my question. Would you mind explaining how to fix the problem? `width: max-content` fixes the first example but not the second one

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: Thanks, so you think this is the right way? `.v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }`

Comment: No, not with the cells widths you said you wanted to use. You need to make the cells only so wide, that the whole table will fit the screen - and then if you have content _inside_ a cell, that is wider than the cell itself, you will be able to scroll within that cell, if you set `overflow: auto` for it. A mechanism to have the whole _column_ scroll as one, if some or all of the cells inside of it have broader content, does not exist with tables & css; that would require a custom solution using JavaScript, I suppose, that modifies the whole structure into something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to achieve this. First you must use this CSS for the `<table>` tag:

```
.v-table__wrapper table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 0 !important;
}
```

**EDIT:**

From the new example you provided in the comment, which involves colspan and rowspan, you need to set all the fixed width explicitly.

[here is the edited demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

**Old answer:**
And then you can define the width for the columns using `nth-child()` CSS selector:

```
.v-table__wrapper table th:nth-child(1),
.v-table__wrapper table td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 300px;
}

.v-table__wrapper table th:nth-child(2),
.v-table__wrapper table td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
}
```

[here is the working demo in playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately my table is dynamic, uses header groups and each columns knows its own width. I don't know how to apply your solution to a dynamic table with loops, I created an example here https://shorturl.at/clyY4

Comment: so cells and groups shouldn't have to deal with a `width` prop :/

Comment: that's actually very different than what you provide in the question, it involves colspan, rowspan, also I see that some cols don't even have fixed width in your new example, is that expected? how do you want the columns to be on the ones that have no width? also how can you make sure that the width on colspanned columns will be the total of the non colspanned column?

Comment: I think only the "last" columns at the "bottom" are "real" columns with data so other ones should have a witdh of "sum widths from children" ( which should be the default behaviour I guess? )

Comment: @baitendbidz please see the updated example, you must set all of the fixed width explicitly

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this requirement by adjusting the `styles` for table and the row elements.

Current styles (Default) **:**

```
.v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Modified style as per the requirement **:**

```
.v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table {
  width: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}

.v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: you mean like so? https://shorturl.at/dCHZ5 The first table seems to have wrong widths, no?

Comment: please also have a look at this comment, it's important for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76627125/how-to-pass-a-fixed-width-to-a-column-in-a-vuetify-html-table#comment135199591_76670264

Comment: @baitendbidz you have to use `!important` to override the default style on `width` property. i.e. `width: 0 !important;`

Comment: I tried to apply your suggested changes but that didn't work, did I miss something? https://shorturl.at/iGNTX